# How to implement user types with different modules using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-management, devise-invitable

I want to use devise to manage my users and my intention is to have one `AgencyUser` model and one `NormalUser` model. They both have some attributes/relations in common, but also have some special attributes/relations. The most significant difference for me is that I want to allow the `NormalUser` to register with the `registerable` module and the `AgencyUser` should only be able to register through the [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) module. Both of them should be able to log in from the same login form.

Do you have any stragecies or advices how I could get such a behaviour?

Thank you!